# Pass output of 'find' command to Python with docopt (issue with spaces)

Tags: python, linux, command-line, docopt

Consider this simple Python command-line script:

```py
"""foobar
  Description

Usage:
  foobar [options] <files>...

Arguments:
  <files>         List of files.

Options:
  -h, --help      Show help.
      --version   Show version.
"""

import docopt

args = docopt.docopt(__doc__)
print(args['<files>'])
```

And consider that I have the following files in a folder:

- `file1.pdf`
- `file 2.pdf`

Now I want to pass the output of the `find` command to my simple command-line script. But when I try

```
foobar `find . -iname '*.pdf'`
```

I don't get the list of files that I wanted, because the input is split on spaces. I.e. I get:

```
['./file', '2.pdf', './file1.pdf']
```

**How can I correctly do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Python question. This is all about how the shell tokenizes command lines.  Whitespace is used to separate command arguments, which is why `file 2.pdf` is showing as as two separate arguments.

You can combine `find` and `xargs` to do what you want like this:

```
find . -iname '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 foobar
```

The `-print0` argument to find tells it to output filenames seperated by ASCII NUL characters rather than spaces, and the `-0` argument to `xargs` tells it to expect that form of input. `xargs` with then call your `foobar` script with the correct arguments.

Compare:

```
$ ./foobar $(find . -iname '*.pdf' )
['./file', '2.pdf', './file1.pdf']
```

To:

```
$ find .  -iname '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 ./foobar
['./file 2.pdf', './file1.pdf']
```